# function call on clicking NgbModal backdrop. anuglar 2 modal

Tags: angular, function, bootstrap-modal, call

I am trying to make a function (Let's say 'randomFunction') call on clicking the backdrop (shaded part) of the modal used in `angular2` using `NgbModal`.

Here is the `companyNumberComponent.html`:

```
<company-numbers-list (companyNumberModal)="modalService.open(companyNumberModal);"></company-numbers-list>

<template ngbModalContainer #companyNumberModal let-c="close" let-d="dismiss" id="companyNumberModal">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <company-number-modal></company-number-modal>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer text-center">
        <mi-button [type]="'info'" id="number_flow_close" [raised]="true" aria-label="close" (click)="c('Close click');
        ">Close</mi-button>
    </div>
```

here is the `companyNumberComponent.ts` file:

```
@Component
 .....
 export class companyNumberComponent(){
     constructor(private modalService: NgbModal){}
     public randomFunction(){
         console.log("hi");
     }
 }
```

Can someone please suggest me how to proceed in this or how to call this `randomFunction()` in the `dismiss()` or `close()` function of the modal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems they are having in the **[docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)**, what you would be looking for, i.e `ModalDismissReasons`:

```ts
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

open(content) {
  this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {}, (reason) => {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC || // if you want to check ESC as well
        reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
        this.randomFunction();
      }
  });
}
```

The close click doesn't seem to be included here at all, so either you can call `randomFunction` on the click event in template_

```ts
(click)="c('Close click'); randomFunction()"
```

or you can do it in the component, but in the first callback, where if the close button is clicked, it seems to throw the string `'Close click'` at you (or whatever you define in template). So then modify the `open` as such:

```ts
open(content) {
  this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
    if(result === 'Close click') {
      this.randomFunction()
    }
  }, (reason) => {
      if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC || 
          reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
          this.randomFunction();
      }
  });
}
```